¿Cómo traducir textos de inglés a español que estén en imágenes de captura de pantalla?
Cómo traducir textos de inglés a español que estén en imágenes de captura de pantalla en un solo documento, especificando texto detectado y traducción realizada.
Recientemente me hicieron la propuesta de ser traductor para un proyecto, y me entregaron el contenido en un pdf lleno de imágenes, solicité el contenido en formato texto pero me lo negaron; como soy desarrollador y se de Python, realicé una clase en Python que me ayude a realizar la tarea de manera eficiente.
Al final detecté que la propuesta de trabajo era una estafa de robo de identidad, para solicitar créditos a nombre del colaborador en los EE.UU. Tengan mucho cuidado. En fin, de todo este mal rato, lo único productivo fué el desarrollo de esta clase de python: se llama GopyFlow:
En la carpeta "images" es donde se debe guardar las imagenes a ser procesadas, y las traducciones se guardarán en la carpeta "translation".

Pregunta:
¿Qué puedo hacer para que el número de imágenes a traducir no sea un problema?
Repositorio:
https://github.com/oigonzalezp2024/gopyFLow/
Aquí el código de programación, nada fuera de lo fundamental:
    import codecs
    import os
    import time
    from PIL import Image
    from googletrans import Translator
    from pytesseract import *
    
    class GopyFlow(Translator):
    
        def setPytesseract(self, pytesseractPath:str)->None:
            self.pytesseract = pytesseract
            self.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = pytesseractPath 
    
        def gopy(self, pathImages:str, pathDest:str)->None:
            images = os.listdir(pathImages)
            result = self.imagesToListText(images, pathImages)
            self.translateToListTextToSpa(images, result, pathDest)
    
        def imagesToListText(self, images:list, pathImages:str)->list:
            result = []
            for i in images:
                img = Image.open(pathImages+i)
                content= self.pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
                result.append(content)
            return result
    
        def translateToListTextToSpa(self, images:list, result:list, pathDest:str)->None:
            j=0
            for i in result:
                contentt = self.translate(i, dest="es")
                image = images[j]
                with codecs.open(pathDest, mode="a", encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    f.write(str("## ")+str(image)+"\n"+str(i)+"\n"+ contentt.text+"\n\n")
                time.sleep(2)
                j+=1


Se usa como sigue:
from gopyFLow import GopyFlow

gopyFlow = GopyFlow()

pytesseractPath = str("C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe")
pathImages = str("./images/")
pathDest = str("./translation/translation.md")

gopyFlow.setPytesseract(pytesseractPath)
gopyFlow.gopy(pathImages, pathDest)

Hasta ahora funciona bien con pocas imágenes (50 Aproximadamente), pero si le mando 200 el código se rompe.

¿Será por algún límite establecido por Google para el consumo de la API? Sin embargo, creo que debe haber alguna posibilidad de optimizar el código para que no se rompa.

Y que error sale???

@gbianchi gracias por preguntar, añadí el reporte de error a la pregunta.

Mas que eso, por el error, suena a un archivo corrupto.. porque no agregas algun tipo de control sobre los archivos?

Igual, como que falta todo el codigo para replicar tu problema, no?

Para replicar el error solo copie varias veces una imagen dentro de la carpeta hasta completar las 200 de imágenes, en github no se permite subir muchos archivos de testeo que no sean de código de programación.

porque querrias subir archivos de testeo a github?? no deberias... en fin.. y como replicamos tu error? donde esta el resto del codigo? yo no soy experto en python, pero me suena a que a todo esto le faltan pedazos...

Todo está dentro del repositorio, pero si quieres puedes recrear el proyecto por ti mismo sin descargar nada. Lo único importante es: la clase que acabo de subir en la actualización de esta pregunta, respetar el orden de las carpetas que se encuentran en el repositorio,  para que el programa sepa cuales son las imágenes a procesar (./images) y donde debe guardar la traducción (./translation). Si se analiza el modo de uso, el proceso es transparente a cualquiera que haya trabajado manejo de archivos con python.

Nada debe estar en un repo en este sitio.. todo debe estar en la pregunta.. la pregunta debe ser autocontenida..

@gbianchi gracias, lo tendré en cuenta.
